# Positivity of generalised heat kernels

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, semigroups-of-operators

Let $K_\alpha(t,x)$ be the (generalised or fractional) *heat kernel* which corresponds to the fractional heat equation (I'm not sure that's the right name) in $\mathbb R^n$
$$
u_t=(-\Delta)^\alpha u, \quad \alpha\in(0,1].
$$

A fact, which appears to be very well-known, states that: 
$$
K_\alpha(t,x)>0, \quad \text{for all $x\in\mathbb R^n,\, t>0$ and $\alpha\in(0,1]$ }.
$$
It is so well-known that no paper where I have encountered this fact gives any reference.

I am looking for a reference where I could see the proof of this fact.

Comment: https://www.ma.utexas.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Fractional_heat_equation

Comment: @Z.Alfata I am aware of this link. Unfortunately, the cited work in the link does not prove what I am looking for. The result I am looking for has been known since before 1960 - It is considered well-known even here: http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1960-095-02/S0002-9947-1960-0119247-6/S0002-9947-1960-0119247-6.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If I guess right you are interested in the monotonicity of the operator. That is, if $u_0 \ge 0$ then $u \ge 0$. This can proved directly, by other means.

From this fact, due to the expression of $u$, and since this is true for every $u_0$, I guess you can prove directly that $K_\alpha \ge 0$.